# Does it make sense use Storyboard and SceneDelegate together?

Tags: ios, storyboard, swiftui

Does it make sense to use `Application Scene Manifest` without SwiftUI? Anyway view controller is added from storyboard ti window already.

I have seen this in an example code, and I am worried it is pointless.

[image]

Comment: If you use the `Launch Storyboard` option from the info plist, the default comments from inside a new sceneDelegate seem to say that its all handled automatically and you don't need to do anything extra. You are using a co-ordinator so you may need to do some extra work such as what you are doing in the image. Should be easy to verify if its needed or not by running with and without the code inside the sceneDelegate.

Comment: My understanding is that the sceneDelegate is not something that was added because of SwiftUI, the two are unrelated. The sceneDelegate was added to separate out functionality. When announced at WWDC they specifically said it was done to unclutter the appDelegate and separate out concerns

Comment: Scene Manifest / Delegate have nothing to do with SwiftUI. The design is to allow your app to display more than one "widow" ... that is, you might have two distinctly different functionality sections of your app, and by using Scenes you can show two sections side-by-side. This article (not mine) looks like a decent description: https://learnappmaking.com/scene-delegate-app-delegate-xcode-11-ios-13/

Comment: Now with the highlighter code and some other code i.e. downloading records from internet are **executed two times** at launch. Which one do you suggest to remove?